# Android Studio not recognizing HTC smartphone

Tags: android-studio

I have a strange issue in Android Studio 3.4.1 as it doesn't recognize my old HTC One V smartphone correctly

When I connect the HTC One V to my PC (Ubuntu 18.04) I see the following device in the ADB:
[image]

And when I try to run an app on it I get an error during the build:

> *com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: insufficient permissions for device: user in plugdev group; are your udev rules
>   wrong?*

Now, other devices (a Moto G2 and a Samsung A5 2013) run well when connected to the PC.

However, when I insert the same HTC smartphone into my laptop with Android Studio 3.2 (also Ubuntu 18.04) I get the proper device name in the ADB:

[image]

and the app runs OK on the HTC.

I checked the SDK settings and the API for Android 4.0.3 is installed on both computers.

I should upgrade the 3.2 Studio on the laptop but am afraid to do so in case I lose the ability to test apps on the HTC with 4.0.3.

The Moto G2 and the Samsung A5 both run well when connected to the PC or the laptop.

Any ideas where to look? Thanks!

Comment: Follow the instructions on setting up a device for development as mentioned in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html). If your `adb` is already in the `plugdev` group, try the solutions suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614067/android-studio-recognizes-physical-device-as-null). This is more likely an issue with the difference in configuration between your PC and laptop, than due to Studio versions.

Comment: Check the below stackoverflow post. It might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820656/android-studio-doesnt-detect-my-device-on-my-ubuntu-laptop/56462463#56462463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Go to location /Android/Sdk/plateform-tools/**

Run Commmands

> if adb server is running

1) adb kill-server

2) adb start-server

Answer (score 0):

I am using

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Android Studio 3.4.1
- One Plus 3T/Android P

Changing **USB Preferences** to **File Transfer** in my phone resolves the issues for me

[image: USB PREFERENCES screen]

[image: When USB mode was on 'No Data Transfer']
[image: After USB mode was changed to 'File Transfer']